# Securing Python-Bottle RESTful API

Tags: jquery, python, json, security, rest

I'm using Python-Bottle to implement a Middleware which bundles data from 2 RESTful APIs and local databases and provides a single REST API to be accessed by a single C++ client being written by a 3rd party.
Local DB is MongoDB and data is being shuffled around in JSON.
I'll also be implementing a JS (JQuery) based API client for administration purposes.

What would be the best way of securing the API?
TLS with mutual authentication is an option for the c++ client.
Since only a very limited number of people (<10) will have access to the admin interface, and I'll only need some basic role management, local storage of roles and password hashes would be preferred.

I've been looking at [Cork](http://cork.firelet.net/) but documentation is a bit scarce and I can't find examples which would fit my use case. OAuth seems just way to complex for my low number of users.

Frankly, I'm a bit overwhelmed by the possibilities and need some guidance about what methods to choose.

Just to clarify, I said "Securing" and imply both authentication and communication encryption.

Comment: Just whatever you do. Don't use passwords.

Comment: You mean for admin interface users? what then?

Comment: For admin interfaces? Use something like mozilla's persona